# Github Pages switched to Jekyll 3 and my links got broken

Tags: jekyll, github-pages

GitHub Pages as of April 2016 [uses Jekyll 3.0](https://github.com/blog/2100-github-pages-now-faster-and-simpler-with-jekyll-3-0). After the switch whenever I push a commit, I get the `Page build failed.` email notification.

Since the error was so uninformative I had to contact GitHub support. It turned out if you use the `exclude` in _config.yaml, the content must be put in bracket now, for example:

```
exclude: [excludethis]
```

Also, Redcarpet and Pygments were no longer available, so they must be replaced by kramdown and rouge in _config.yaml:

```
markdown: kramdown
highlighter: rouge
```

And now by default future posts (posts with `date` in the future) are NOT published. So if you have `date: 2016-04-25 09:30:00` in your post and now is 10:00 at your place but you are in Asia and the server is in the US, then this post is considered in the future and not published. Setting `timezone` in `_config.yml` doesn't help (bug?). You have to add offset to the date like so:

```
date: 2016-04-25 09:30:00 +0700
```

After these changes commit push no longer produced errors. But I encountered another error, all my links are broken, and all old URLs for posts returned 404.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out with Jekyll 3 posts no longer end with a trailing slash.

Previously I set the URL for posts to be like this in `_config.yaml`:

```
permalink: /article/:title
```

Example URL would be: http://mysite/article/apost/

With Jekyll 3 this URL cannot be found (404). But I can get it with http://mysite/article/apost.

So if you want to maintain old URLs, permalink needs to be modified to have trailing slash:

```
permalink: /article/:title/
```

And links to posts need to be modified to remove the trailing slash. For example if previously you would have:

```
<a href="{{post.url}}/">
```

It needs to be changed to:

```
<a href="{{post.url}}">
```

This solves the problem for posts. Non post pages have different problem. Previously if you have for example `about.md` in root, Jekyll would convert it to http://mysite/about.html. Jekyll 3 will not append `.html` at the end, it would become http://mysite/about.

If you want to maintain the old URL, you can add permalink in the 'front matter' of *each* page:

```
---
permalink: /about.html
---
```

Comment: Yep! For reference on upgrading Jekyll 2 to 3 with GitHub Pages, read through this [article](http://blog.virtuacreative.com.br/upgrade-jekyll-2-to-3-gh-pages.html)